# Access 2016 - Select Unique Non Overlapping Dates

Tags: ms-access

I need to query many records that have a start and end date & time field. Where there are overlapping dates & times then the result needs to be the earliest start and latest end. i.e. 
    Main_ID timestart timeend
    40952 02/10/2014 06:00:00 02/10/2014 17:00:00
    40957 02/10/2014 10:00:00 02/10/2014 17:00:00
    40956 02/10/2014 15:00:00 02/10/2014 17:00:00
    40965 02/10/2014 18:30:00 04/10/2014
    40967 02/10/2014 20:00:00 02/10/2014 21:30:00
    40968 02/10/2014 21:30:00 04/10/2014
    40972 03/10/2014 03/10/2014 06:00:00
    40973 03/10/2014 03:00:00 03/10/2014 06:00:00
    40976 03/10/2014 04:00:00 03/10/2014 06:00:00
    40978 03/10/2014 06:00:00 03/10/2014 12:00:00
    40983 03/10/2014 13:00:00 03/10/2014 16:00:00
    40986 03/10/2014 15:00:00 03/10/2014 18:00:00
    40989 03/10/2014 18:00:00 03/10/2014 22:00:00
    40992 03/10/2014 22:00:00 05/10/2014
    87140 10/06/2015 21:10:00 12/06/2015
    87219 11/06/2015 11/06/2015 05:45:00
    87218 11/06/2015 21:00:00 13/06/2015

The results should be:

```
Main_ID timestart Main_ID timeend  
40952 02/10/2014 06:00:00  40956 02/10/2014 17:00:00  
40965 02/10/2014 18:30:00  40992 05/10/2014  
87140 10/06/2015 21:10:00  87218 13/06/2015
```

Comment: Please edit your question and use http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to format the data.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? You need to show some effort in order to get help.

Comment: Data formatted:

Comment: I've tried the following but have exhausted my ability in SQL..

Comment: SELECT q_Clash.WEC, q_Clash.TimeStart, Min(q_Clash.FirstOfMain_ID) AS xMain_ID, Max(CDate([q_clash].[timestart]+[q_clash].[timeend]-[q_clash].[timestart])) AS te, [Q_CLASH_1].[TimeStart]=[Q_CLASH].[TimeStart] AS Expr1
FROM q_Clash, q_Clash AS q_Clash_1
GROUP BY q_Clash.WEC, q_Clash.TimeStart, [Q_CLASH_1].[TimeStart]=[Q_CLASH].[TimeStart]
HAVING ((([Q_CLASH_1].[TimeStart]=[Q_CLASH].[TimeStart])=True));

Comment: I would really appreciate some assistance with this rather than criticism of how I have posted the question and then silence thereafter

Answer (score 0):

To prevent collisions, the logic here is quite simple:

A collision occurs when: 
RequestStartDate <= EndDate 
and 
RequestEndDate >= StartDate

The above is thus a rather simply query, but if any collision occurs, (including any overlapping) the above will return records, and you simply don’t allow the booking. In other words, since we NEVER allow booking with a collision, then the above simply statement will work for us.

So to get ANY KIND of overlap, then code will look like this:

```
dim strWhere                 as string 
dim dtRequeestStartDate      as date 
dim dtRequestEndDate         as date 


dtRequestStartDate = inputbox("Enter start Date") 
dtRequestEndDate = inputbox("Enter end date") 

strWhere="#" & format(dtRequestStartDate,"mm/­dd/yyyy") & "# <= EndDate" & _ 
 " and #" & format(dtRequestEndDate,"mm/dd­/yyyy") & "#  >= StartDate" 


if dcount("*","tableBooking",strWhere) > 0 then 
    msgbox "sorry, you can’t book 
    ...bla bla bla....
```

The above is just an example, and I am sure you would build a nice form that prompts the user for the booking dates. However, what is nice here is that the simple conditions above does return ANY collisions.

You can also use the above “where” clause to say launch a report that will thus show all collisions for a given date range. (just pass the "strWhere" in the "where" parameter of the openform, or open report.

Keep in mind that the date part can include the “time” portion, and thus even for bookings or events in a given day, the above query will return any date/time range that overlaps.

Once you have the above data set (I assume your query this data).

At this point, on the resulting data set, you would simple do a dmin() on the start column, or sort by descend to show the most early time first.

Comment: Thanks Albert but unfortunately it doe not help me as I have found that solution already which is not the solution to my problem.

Comment: I've taken a little step further but cannot get the following to work...

Comment: SELECT Query2.WEC, Min(Query2.Main_ID) AS MinOfMain_ID, Query2.TimeStart, Query2.TimeEnd, [query2_1].[TimeStart]>=[query2].[TimeStart] And [query2_1].[TimeEnd]<=[query2].[TimeEnd] AS NoClash
FROM Query2, Query2 AS Query2_1
GROUP BY Query2.WEC, Query2.TimeStart, Query2.TimeEnd, [query2_1].[TimeStart]>=[query2].[TimeStart] And [query2_1].[TimeEnd]<=[query2].[TimeEnd]
HAVING ((([query2_1].[TimeStart]>=[query2].[TimeStart] And [query2_1].[TimeEnd]<=[query2].[TimeEnd])=True))
ORDER BY Query2.TimeStart;